# How to use timeapi.io API with JS?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm using another API without problems, like this:

```
fetch("https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity").then(r => r.text()).then(console.log);
```

But this doesn't work:

```
fetch("https://www.timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timeZone=Brazil/East").then(r => r.text()).then(console.log);
```

With the code above I'm getting a blank response :(

Comment: Try this it's working - fetch("https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity").then(r => r.text()).then((data) => console.log(data));

Comment: My problem is with the second case - timeapi.io

Comment: You are not able to access second API endpoint because it is cors enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns cors error.

You can use backend to download data or use proxy